# Unsubscribing to previous domain provider (godaddy.com, onamae.com) after moving to Amazon Route 53

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, godaddy, amazon-route53

I'm new to AWS Route 53 and Domain transfer. So far I'm successful in transferring my DNS Settings from onamae.com(Japanese equivalent of godaddy.com) to AWS-Route 53. But since I'm new, I still don't know if i could unsubscribe my account in onamae.com. Does onamae has some connection to route-53 or the other way around?

Update - DNS settings copied from below.

```
Domain Name: FOOBAR.COM 
Registrar: AMAZON REGISTRAR, INC.
Sponsoring Registrar IANA ID: XXXX
Whois Server: whois.registrar.amazon.com
Referral URL: http://registrar.amazon.com
Name Server: NS-XXXX.AWSDNS-XXXX.XXXX
Name Server: NS-XXXX.AWSDNS-XXXX.XXXX.XXXX
Name Server: NS-XXXX.AWSDNS-XXXX.XXXX
Name Server: NS-XXXX.AWSDNS-XXXX.XXXX
Status: clientTransferProhibited 
Updated Date: 
Creation Date: 
Expiration Date:
```

Comment: Careful with unsubscribing, you could loose your domain name. What exactly have you done? have you transfered the registration of your domain name to Route 53? Or just copied the zone? Have you changed nameservers of your domain?

Comment: Hi Marvin, Yes I did transfer the registration from onamae to route53, and used the NS records provided by route53. What I actually did was similar to this tutorial.    

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OxuqoqzjZYI&t=481s

Answer (score 0):

DNS providers typically offer two services

- Domain Registration
- DNS server (this is often included at no charge)

If you're transferring your domain registration into Route53 you can close the onamae account once the domain has been transferred. There's a bit of a process to get it transferred, it's not possible to do accidentally. If you're just moving to Route53 for DNS then you need to leave the other registrar open - changing your DNS server is relatively trivial, a configuration setting.

You can use a WhoIs service to work out the domain registrar. Have a look at [this whois service](https://www.whois.net/). When you use it it will tell you your registrar. The trick here is sometimes registrars partner with others so you see a name you don't expect. I use NameCheap to register my domains but the whois looking says "enom" is my domain registrar. It's at least a clue toward the registrar.

Comment: Thank you Tim, I checked domain using whois and all information is connected to aws and doesn't mention any thing from onamae or other registrars.

Comment: I added my dns details above as an answer,

Comment: From what that says your registrar is Amazon and your name servers are AWS Route 53. That suggests that you can cancel your other registrar, though they shouldn't be charging you for anything anyway as they aren't providing any services. Remember this is just advice, I don't have full visibility, and you need to be confident that you no longer need the other provider before closing that account.

Comment: Thanks Tim, much help by the way, do you know what will happen when i use the NS records provided by aws route 53 instead of what onamae provided.

Comment: Yes, Amazon will become your DNS server. I assumed you got the above using whois and that AWS was live as your registrar and DNS server. I think you'd better share your actual domain name so we can take a look, as based on your comments I'm not confident that you've described the actual situation accurately. That means the advice I've given above could be incorrect and it could cause significant problems for you if you do something wrong.